# Chrome other devices history

Tags: google-chrome, history

After raid0 failure on my desktop computer about two weeks ago I have lost access to chrome tabs there. They were visible in device history list on my laptop, but I was busy and did not reopen them. Now I finally installed new ssd in my desktop pc, but open tabs history list from my desktop disappeared this morning. Is there a way to get access to open tabs list or is it expired and gone forever?

Answer (score 0):

Your profile should have your settings and history saved online and you should be able to restore these things when logging in your profile.

Do check the history settings if there's an option where you can view the whole history from all devices where you entered with your profile.

In the same settings part you should be able to see a link that holds your browsing history, again from devices where you used your login credentials.

Comment: I was able to see it yesterday evening. It was late, I decided to open tabs in the morning. And now there is no history list from my old desktop computer at all. I can see history from android phone, from laptop, from my work pc, but my home desktop list is not there. May be there is some expiration time, say 2 weeks?

Comment: Unless you are using an additional application that limits the expiration date of your browsing history or delete it manually it shouldn't expire at all and shouldn't get deleted. Provided you used your account to get signed in and haven't deleted any history it should be visible at all times. 

The easiest way would be to contact Google for this and see what the guys there can say about it.